# Docker: Change permission of all files previously created as root within the container to local user

Tags: docker

I have been working with a docker container for a few months now and was unaware of the fact that everything I was creating (folders, files) were created under the `root` user of my container. Now I want to reclaim ownership over all of these files so that I can have the permissions to move or write into them while I am outside of the container.

To make it a bit more concrete/clear, I have a local user named `johndoe`, and a local folder under the path of `/home/johndoe/pythoncodes` which is owned by `johndoe`. I mount this local folder to my docker container when I run the command

`docker run -v /home/johndoe/pythoncodes:/home/johndoe/pythoncodes ...`

Then when inside my container, I created a folder at `/home/johndoe/pythoncodes/ProjectRepo`. `ProjectRepo` is now owned by `root` from the container and so when I leave the container and go back to being the `johndoe` user, I no longer have the permissions to do anything with this folder (e.g. if I try to run `git init` I get a permission error that doesn't allow the creation of the `.git` folder.

I have seen answers on how to create a container that logs me in as my local user and have gotten this to work as well by using the `adduser` flag, but this only seem helpful for creating new files and doesn't help me with all of these files that have been already created as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but this only seem helpful for creating new files and doesn't help me with all of these files that have been already created as root

You could directly use `chown` from within the docker container to change the ownership of these bind mounts. But for this to work you will need to mount two folders which contain the username and password information for your user, `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` (below, `:ro` means 'read-only').

```
$ docker run -idt -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro --name try ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash 
$ docker exec -it try mkdir -p /tmp/abc/newfolder
$ cd abc
$ ls -alh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 atg atg  4.0K Jul  7 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 60 atg atg  4.0K Jul  7 16:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root 4.0K Jul  7 16:43 newfolder
$ sudo chown -R atg:atg .
[sudo] password for atg:
$ ls -alh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 atg atg 4.0K Jul  7 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 60 atg atg 4.0K Jul  7 16:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 atg atg 4.0K Jul  7 16:43 newfolder
```

Comment: Your comment got me going in the right direction, but I did need to follow some extra steps to make it work. I will edit the extra steps I took into your answer and then accept it :)